# Can't find cached and buffer from 'cat /proc/meminfo'

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

I want to find cached memory and buffer memory here. But unlike linux, bash does not give me all the information as expected. How can I find *cached memory*, *shared memory* and *buffer memory*?

I used the following line of codes to extract information, which I failed while finding buffer, cached and shared memory.

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

and

```
declare -i totalk=$(awk '/^MemFree:{print $2}' /proc/meminfo)
echo "memory free: $memfree"
```

I am using *Git Bash* in *Windows*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask this on unix.stackexchange.com. However, the answer is, /proc/meminfo is not guaranteed to have this info. Use the command free like this:

```
$free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16393544      606076    14766732        1160     1020736    15520496
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it shows "bash: free: command not found"
I am assuming this happens since I am using Gitbash on Windows rather than Linux.

Comment: @Jd_mahmud: sorry to hear that. What happens if you call vmstat or top | grep free

Comment: @Jd_mahmud: just thinking... MAYBE gitbash just request RAM from Windows, but does not know how much is left there.

Comment: It does not recognize "top" as a command. Is it because I am using Gitbash on Windows?
I am completely new here. Learning bash script for about two days. So I am trying to get as much clear idea as possible here.

Comment: @Jd_mahmud: Welcome, happy to support Newcomers, I have a bash tutorial at www.linuxintro.org/wiki/babe AND yes, you are correct, most probably Gitbash does not have all programs that you would find in a "normal" Bash environment. vmstat is a great command, does it exist?

Comment: I tried that as well. Sadly none of the traditional commands are working. 
Do you suggest me to install linux or some VM to practice all these commands?
It would be amazing to have some legitimate guidelines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239643/discussion-between-thorsten-staerk-and-jd-mahmud).